# FusionCharts . Pbarloadingtext Localization

Tags: localization, fusioncharts

I've tried to localize chart on russian. All messages were translated ok, but PBarLoadingText shows wrong symbols.Here is my code:

```
var renderMyChart = new FusionCharts(fileRenderChartType, "myChartDataId" + i, "100%", "100%", "0", "1");
renderMyChart.setXMLData($(this).html());
renderMyChart.setTransparent(true);
```

where `fileRenderChartType`="..../flash/MSColumn3D.swf?ChartNoDataText=График пустой по причине отсутствия данный для него&PBarLoadingText=Загрузка...";

Problem is in `PBarLoadingText` only. Firebug shows parameters correctly. I tried to use configure method instead of it, but I got the same result.

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct property is LoadingText not PBarLoadingText, i have tested it and it works.
may some one from FusionCharts update the document soon, so that it helps all.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

LoadingText seems For JavaScript charts only.
http://docs.fusioncharts.com/charts/contents/advanced/ChartMessages.html

Comment: Avoid answering with only a link, give a more detailed explanation and provide the link as source